# Solidity get contract balance showing different value than during HartHat

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

I'm running into an issue where my Solidity contract balance isn't matching my Chai test contract balance. Running my contract on a local instance of HardHat

using solidity ^0.8.0

My contract gets the current contract balance with:

```
uint balance = address(this).balance;
```

> 0

My Chai test gets the contract balance with:

```
const contractBalance = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);
```

> BigNumber { value: "42278041630000000001" }

I verified the contract addresses are the same with my trust console

```
Chai Test --
contractAddress: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180bb3
contractBalance: BigNumber { value: "42278041630000000001" }

Contract Execution --
contractAddress 0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180bb3
contractBalance 0
```

What could I be missing to cause these balances to be not identical? There's no additional test logic being ran before this

-- here's the full contract code contracts/Contract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Contract {

  function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {

    uint balance = address(this).balance;

    console.log("\nContract Execution -- ");
    console.log("contractAddress", address(this));
    console.log("contractBalance", balance);

    return balance;
  }
}
```

-- full test file code test/index.js

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Contract", function () {
  let contract;
  let provider;
  let contractAddress;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const _Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Contract");
    const _contract = await _Contract.deploy();
    await _contract.deployed();
    contract = _contract;
    contractAddress = contract.address;
    provider = await ethers.getDefaultProvider();
  });

  it("should have a consistent account balance", async function () {
    const contractBalance = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);

    console.log("\nChai Test -- ");
    console.log("contractAddress:", contractAddress);
    console.log("contractBalance:", contractBalance);

    expect(await contract.getBalance()).to.equal(contractBalance);
  });
});
```

-- full hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
};
```

-- and to help you get running if you want to test yourself package.json devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.4",
  "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.1",
  "bignumber.js": "^9.0.2",
  "chai": "^4.3.4",
  "chai-bignumber": "^3.0.0",
  "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.0",
  "ethers": "^5.5.3",
  "hardhat": "^2.8.2"
},
```

so just organize the files as such and npx hardhat, copy devDependencies, npm i, `npx hardhat test`

Comment: Did you deploy the contract to that address? The chain that runs in the test suite in hardhat should be temporary. Anything you do inside your test suite probably won't persist in a local environment and is not expected to.

Comment: Well the console.logs are being printed *by* the test run, so it deploys the contract to Hardhat, prints the same address, and then runs the tests on that hardhat instance...so by definition it's all the same unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Wild guess: You're requesting the balance onchain and offchain at different stages of the test (onchain when it's really 0, and offchain after it's been increased because of some test logic) ... Can you provide steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Can you share more of the code? Are you doing the `Contract Execution` in the test suite or outside?

Comment: @PetrHejda added files and way to reproduce locally

Comment: @DogEatDog added all code from a new minimal project example and a way to run/test locally

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using following code as indicated here https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers.html#provider-object

```
const an_other_bal = await ethers.provider.getBalance(acceptEther.address);
```